# How to attached image from post to email in Ruby

Tags: ruby, image, email, post

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I have a project using Ruby version 2.6.5. This project have a post with image using imagemagick. when i create a new post, currently i can send the post to my email, but without the post's images.

How to do to attached email with the image's post?

what i have done:-

```
class NotifierMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: ENV['ADMIN_MAIL']
  layout 'mailer'

  def new_post(post)
    @post = post
    mail(to: @post.email,
    bcc: ENV['ADMIN_MAIL'],
    subject: " New Post.")
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

So, it is irrelevant if you use ImageMagick or not. The way to solve this is by
doing something like this:

```
def new_post(post, file_path)
    @post = post
    # You can add multiple attachments in a loop, just ensure the file names are uniq
    attachments[File.basename(file_path)] = File.read(file_path)
    mail(to: @post.email,
    bcc: ENV['ADMIN_MAIL'],
    subject: " New Post.")
end
```

The key here is that the file needs to be locally available, which it should be as this is a new post. If not you need to download the file to a temp file first, or you won't have a local file path to read from.

Comment: hi @TTD , do you have any examples or references for this **attachments[File.basename(file_path)] = File.read(file_path)** ?

Comment: Hi, that is the example. `ApplicationMailer` has a method called `attachments` that takes in a filename in the brackets. So you can swap out `File.basename(file_path)` with any string, `File.read(file_path)` is the bytes read from the file, aka the file you want to add as an attachment. So if you already have the file stream saved in a variable you can use that instead.

Comment: i manage to do this :- `attachments.inline['logo.png'] = { data: File.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/img/logo.png')), mime_type: 'image/png' }` for static image. How about dynamic images? for example i have a model call _post_, and when i do _post_ with new images uploaded, the image also send as attached to email?

Comment: If you want to add a inline logo your code is correct, don't think you need to wrap it in the data hash though. If you want to add images as a normal attachment to an email the example above works for both dynamic and static images. If you want different encoding or changing mimetype, you can do it like this. encoded_content = SpecialEncode(File.read('/path/to/filename.jpg'))
attachments['filename.jpg'] = {
  mime_type: 'application/gzip',
  encoding: 'SpecialEncoding',
  content: encoded_content
}

Comment: right.. i understand now.. if i want to attach images from Post, i have to convert it for email attachments.. isn't it??